# Angular typescript - how to remove space in between words in component.html

Tags: angular, typescript, removing-whitespace

In my component.html I have a img tag, the image source value comes form an array.
The array consists of a property called name. The name can be two or 3 words with white spaces in between the words.
How to set the the image src to the "name" property of the array, **without the white spaces in between the words**.

```
Array - item[0] : 
{
description: "fruits",
name: "Apple orange pear",
age: "30"
}


HTML :
 <img [src]="item.name" [alt]="item.description"> ---- here the item.name if it has any whitespaces in between should be removed.
```

How to achieve this in the component.html template itself ?

Comment: As far as I know this isn't something you can do in HTML/CSS directly. You'll probably need an angular pipe or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since @Andrei Tatar didn't post an answer with an example on how it can be done with a pipe, I put this together to show how easy it is to manipulate data with pipes.

```
@Pipe({
  name: "trimWhitespace"
})
export class TrimWhitespacePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value.replace(/\s/g,'')
  }
}
```

and use it with  `<img [src]="item.name | trimWhitespace"`